# eacces error whlle running npm install -g composer-cli

Tags: node.js, npm, hyperledger-fabric, npm-install

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /home/akash2/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/.staging/grpc-b403b8a1/node_modules/mkdirp
npm ERR! dest /home/akash2/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/.staging/mkdirp-13f83417
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/home/akash2/.npm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/akash2/.npm/_logs/2021-05-07T05_37_52_411Z-debug.log
```

These are the errors. I am trying to fix this, but can't.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the error and follow the instructions.  ```sudo chown -R 1000:0000 /home/akash2/.npm```  is what it says.  Have you done that?

Comment: yes I have executed this command, but the error remain unchanged.